# Como adicionar colunas e valores nas colunas num ListView em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Possuo um `ListView listViewListaChamada` e estou tentando adcionar colunas e valores as colunas correspondente ao meu `ListView listViewListaChamada`, porem não obtive sucesso. Criei a função abaixo para popular meu ListView:

```
private void PopulaListView(MListaPresenca lista_chamada, ListView listview, MAluno aluno) 
{
    listview.Items[0].SubItems.Add(aluno.Nome);
    listview.Items[1].SubItems.Add(lista_chamada.Presente);
}
```

Onde a primeira coluna recebe o `nome` do aluno e a segunda coluna recebe o valor do atributo `Presente` cujo o valor pode ser `SIM` ou `NÃO`, sendo assim meu `ListView` ficara com duas colunas, porem, no momento de inserir os valores recebo o seguinte erro:

> "InvalidArgument=Value '0' não é um valor válido para 'index'.\r\nNome
>   do parâmetro: index"

Eu gostaria de sabe como adicionar colunas e valores nas colunas do meu `ListView` em tempo de execução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente tive que criar as colunas:

```
listViewListaChamada.View = View.Details;
listViewListaChamada.Columns.Add("Aluno", 490);
listViewListaChamada.Columns.Add("Presente", 100);
```

Defini a rotina acima no evento `Load` do meu formulário.

Em seguida fiz a modificação no método `PopulaListView`, veja como ficou:

```
private void PopulaListView(ListView listview, string nome,  string presente) 
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new []{nome, presente});    
    listview.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Só foi efetuar a chamada do método passando os parâmetros e obtive sucesso.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/473291/5429980).